Is $\operatorname{Hom}_k(R,k) \cong E(k)$ for a local ring $R$?
Let $(R,m)$ be a local noetherian ring, which is also a $k$-algebra over a filed $k$. Suppose $R/m \cong k$. We can consider module $M=\operatorname{Hom}_k(R,k)$. Using the standard argument (the same that show that $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ is an injective cogenerator) we can conclude that $M$ is an injective cogenerator. Another injective cogenerator is the injective hull of the residue field $E(k)$.
How this two injective cogenerators are related in general? Is it true that $M \cong E(k)$? If not in general for what rings this is true?

This is interesting ... I can shed some partial light: the isomorphism in your title is affirmative if $R$ is moreover an Artinian ring; indeed in this case, $R$ is a finite dimensional $k$-vector space, and so the dualizing module of $R$ would be given by $\text{Hom}_k(R,k)$, but which we also know to be $E(k)$ since $R$ is Artinian.
